# youtube-dl unable to download the webpage

Tags: html, dll, download, youtube-dl

I have downloaded the youtube-dl & when I am trying to download the gaming course from Udemy.
**It show me below error:**

[udemy:course] Downloading login popup
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

**I am using this command:**

youtube-dl -u user@gmail.com -p password https://www.udemy.com/course/gaming-youtube-masterclass/

Anyone please tell me how to fix this issue. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hi Javier issue not solved yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Udemy has updated something in their platform and youtube-dl is no longer able to download. I downloaded the last version of youtube-dl to see if the team has fixed the issue but unfortunately it is not until today. I reported this issue in GitHub and I hope they will fix it soon.